# Adding Middleware to a MassTransit Publish channel

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm building a system that has components that communicate via a publish subscribe pattern.  I need to pass certain contextual data with every message that I publish.  I want to enrich the message on the outgoing pipeline specifically with the Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class AddPrincipalFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : class, PipeContext
{
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
    }

    public async Task Send(T context, IPipe<T> next)
    {
        var msg = context.GetPayload<MessageBase>();
        msg.Principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("AddUserIdFilter");
        await next.Send(context);
    }
}

public class AddPrincipalSpecification<T> :
    IPipeSpecification<T> where T : class, PipeContext
{
    public void Apply(IPipeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("In Apply");
        builder.AddFilter(new AddPrincipalFilter<T>());
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<ValidationResult>();
    }
}

public  static class AddPrincipalExtensions
{
    public static void UseAddPrincipalFilter<T>(this IPipeConfigurator<T> configurator)
        where T : class, PipeContext
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("In UserPrincipalFilter");
        configurator.AddPipeSpecification(new AddPrincipalSpecification<T>());
    }
}

var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator x;
    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"),
        h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });
        cfg.UseAddUserFilter();
});

bus.Publish(new TestMessage { Name = "Jeff" });
```

The middleware gets properly configured (or rather the UseAddPrincipalFilter and Apply methods get called) but the AddPrincipalFilter.Send never gets called and so the message doesn't get enriched with the CurrentPrincipal.

Is there anything else I should be doing in order to get the middleware to be called when I publish?

Comment: You might look at this question on how to add middleware on send/publish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008671/masstransit-adding-headers-to-publish-pipeline

Comment: @Chris: That was perfect