# MassTransit: Adding Headers to Publish Pipeline

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit 3.2.4 and I'm trying to add some header information for to my published messages but the code to set the header never seems to run. I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
{
    var host = config.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h {});
    config.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "TestPublisher", e => 
    { 
        e.ConfigurePublish(x => x.UseSendExecute(context =>
            context.Headers.Set("HeaderKey", "HeaderValue")
        ));
    });
});
```

On the consumer end I'm trying to read the header

```
public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IActionHappened> context)
{
    var headerValue = context.Headers.Get("HeaderKey", "Default Value");
}
```

Do I need to add an interceptor or something else in order to set header information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out after much guessing. Just had the ConfigurePublish in the wrong place

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config => 
{
    var host = config.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h => {});
    config.ConfigurePublish(x => x.UseSendExecute(context => 
    {
        context.Headers.Set("HeaderKey", "HeaderValue");
    }));
}
```

Comment: If you are using the IBus to publish, this is correct. A publish within the receive endpoint consumer should have worked, in the case where it was configured within the receive endpoint.