# How to copy headers to PublishContext/SendContext from ConsumeContext in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying copy headers (TenantId basically) when Publish/Send messages during Consuming like MassTransit does with Correlation/Conversation Ids.

There are topics on SO how to modify publish pipeline [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008671/masstransit-adding-headers-to-publish-pipeline), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945303/can%C2%B4t-add-header-to-masstransit-message-from-operationcontext)  but all of them add some hardcoded values. But I need to transfer data from Consume to Publish/Send pipelines.

There's method called `TransferConsumeContextHeaders` which does exactly what I need but I need somehow access `ConsumeContext` which is not available in `ConfigurePublish` method.

Thank you in advance.

**UPD**:
Managed to achieve this like in the code below, however I'm not sure if it's good idea.

```
var consumeContext = context.GetPayload<ConsumeContext>();
context.TransferConsumeContextHeaders(consumeContext);
```

[Here's](https://github.com/elepner/MTExperiments/blob/master/MTUtils/MassTransitExtensions.cs#L35-L39) full example.

Comment: There's an overload for `Publish` and `Send` that accepts a delegate, which can set the headers.

Comment: Yes there's, but I need to intercept all ``Publish`` and ``Send`` and copy headers data from Consume to Publish/Send.

Comment: `GetPayload` is completely legit

Comment: For safety, you might use `TryGetPayload` and only transfer the headers if the consume context is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments and some wild guesses here's the way how one can access ConsumeContext from Publish/Send: `context.TryGetPayload(out ConsumeContext consumeContext)`.

Then it's possible to do whatever one wants with incoming data like copying some important data to Publish/Send in generic way.