# How to reach ConsumeContext from SendFilter in Masstransit?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit, .net-7.0

This issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1474) and fixed by @chris-patterson but I really did not understand how to apply into my code.

Summary:

I have a scenario that adding Token every event's header just before sent. I am able to do that with `Send Scoped Filter` in Masstransit. So in the SendFilter, I am getting the Token from `HttpContext` and adding the header then I am able to get this token from header while consuming via `ConsumeContext` or `Consume Scoped Filter`.Everything is so good so far, but when I need to send another event during the consuming, this time in the SendFilter I can not reach ConsumeContext, I am getting `MissingConsumeContext Exception`.I have seen creting a scoped object for both `SendFilter` and `ConsumeFilter`. But it just did not work for me. This is the [link](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/middleware/scoped#combining-consume-and-sendpublish-filters) for combining consume and send filter. This [repo](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters/blob/master/src/WebApi/Filters/TokenSendFilter.cs) is actually the same with my use case, only difference is i am not using request/response client for sending messages.

My Code looks like:

```
public class TokenSendFilter<T> : IFilter<SendContext<T>> where T : class
    {

        private MyDependency myDependency;
        private readonly IWorkContext _workcontext;

        public TokenSendFilter(MyDependency dependency, IWorkContext workcontext)
        {
            myDependency = dependency;
            _workcontext = workcontext;
        }

        public Task Send(SendContext<T> context, IPipe<SendContext<T>> next)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_workcontext.Token))
            {
                myDependency.Token = _workcontext.Token;
                context.Headers.Set("Token", _workcontext.Token);
            }
            else if((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myDependency.Token)))
            {
                context.Headers.Set(key: "Token", myDependency.Token);
            }
            return next.Send(context);
        }
        public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
        {
        }
    }

public class TokenConsumeFilter<T> : IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>> where T : class
    {
        private MyDependency myDependency;

        public TokenConsumeFilter(MyDependency dependency)
        {
            myDependency = dependency;
        }

        public Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
        {

            if (context.Headers.TryGetHeader("Token", out object token))
            {
                myDependency.Token = (string)token;
            }

            return next.Send(context);
        }

        public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

**IWorkContext is just an abstraction to get HttpContext header values.

Registering the scoped filters :

```
services.AddScoped<MyDependency>();

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<MyConsumer>();

                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.UseSendFilter(typeof(TokenSendFilter<>), context);
                    cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(TokenConsumeFilter<>), context);

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });
```

Sending the event:

```
var address = new Uri($"exchange:{exchangeName}");

var endpoint = await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(address);

await endpoint.Send(The Message);
```

I also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268609/how-to-copy-headers-to-publishcontext-sendcontext-from-consumecontext-in-masstra) but It did not find the ConsumeContext payload in SendContext Filter.

I believe the SendFiler is out of the scope of ConsumeContext so I need to get ConsumeContext object while sending another event.

Masstransit version(8.05)

Any suggestion would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`IBus` is not scoped, so using `_bus.GetSendEndpoint()` isn't going to work. You must use `ISendEndpointProvider`, which is scoped and will be resolved in the current scope.

> Also, v8.0.5 is ancient, I'd suggest upgrading to the latest release.